# 0x80070002 when trying to set default browser

Tags: c++, windows, com

I'm trying to set the default browser on Windows. I did have it working, and then for some reason it stopped when I refactored my code and I can't work out why (and I can't get the old code back unfortunately).

Here is a test I wrote which I believe should work:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Shobjidl.h>

void test()
{
    // Included because they aren't defined in mingw for some reason.
    const GUID CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration =
        { 0x591209c7, 0x767b, 0x42b2, {0x9f,0xba,0x44,0xee,0x46,0x15,0xf2,0xc7} };

    const IID IID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration =
        { 0x4e530b0a, 0xe611, 0x4c77, {0xa3,0xac,0x90,0x31,0xd0,0x22,0x28,0x1b} };

    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);

    IApplicationAssociationRegistration* pAAR;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration,
                                  NULL,
                                  CLSCTX_INPROC,
                                  IID_ApplicationAssociationRegistration,
                                  (void**)&pAAR);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        qDebug() << "CoCreateInstance failed: " << hr;
        return;
    }

    hr = pAAR->SetAppAsDefault(L"IE.HTTP", L"http", AT_URLPROTOCOL);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        qDebug() << "SetAppAsDefault failed: " << hr;
        pAAR->Release();
        return;
    }

    pAAR->Release();

    qDebug() << "Success";
    return;
}
```

I get `"SetAppAsDefault failed: -2147024894"` (0x80070002). Note that `CoCreateInstance` *does* work (or at least claims to).

Any ideas? I've tried changing `COINT_APARTMENTTHREADED` to various other values, and `CLSCTX_INPROC` too. None of them work. Please explain your answer as if I have never used COM before and have no desire to fill my brain with it! I.e. I have no idea what marshalling, apartments, etc. are.

I'm 80% sure something very similar to this *did* work...

*Update*: Sorry I previously said it was giving E_NOINTERFACE which was totally wrong - not sure why I thought that. 0x80070002 doesn't appear to be anything though...

*Update 2*: 0x80070002 means "The system cannot find the file specified." according to FormatMessage. I have no idea how that makes sense in this context though.

Comment: Sounds like classic registry redirector trouble.  Compile your program to x64 if you target the 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: Actually I found the problem was with my value (IE.HTTP). I gave up on this browser setting method and switched to `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Shell\\Associations\\UrlAssociations\\http\\UserChoice` instead...

Comment: Sure, that's a key that's shared between 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

Follow Microsoft's guidelines when working with the default browser as you will encounter many issues on many os versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144154(v=vs.85).aspx#browser